# Dot net grid view functionality in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

How can I bind a `GridView` in android like in dot net. See the code below it will give you delete button for each row.Is there any similar functionality in android.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSample" runat="server" Width="100%" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID,Place,MAddress" OnRowCommand="gvSensors_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DeviceName" HeaderText="S ID">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="MCountry" HeaderText="COUNTRY">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MState" HeaderText="STATE">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnSelect" ImageUrl="~/img/select.png" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
            CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="Select" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkbtnDelete" ImageUrl="~/img/delete.png" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
            CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="DeleteC" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android there is no such automatic functionality provided by the `IDE` or `SDK`.

First of all you need to create custom `xml layout` having your fields with Select and Delete button and then you will have to use that `layout` with `Custom Adapter` for `GridView`. You may use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` for the same. You will get lot of tutorials on how to do these things.

Comment: I thought I can select two your got deselected when I clicked the other one.

Comment: @shijithmc yes that's what happened. And this is very wrong practice. You should always compare for the best answer

Comment: Your answer has more clarity, But if change now I may get blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Their is no direct functionality in android, in the dotnet, it is table rather than grid as all row defines single item. For this you can use listView, each list item spans attributes of item with options views like delete. When you click on delete, remove item from list and call notifyDataSetChanged in the list adapter.